# Using query in google sheet to call certain rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to get all the rows where `A=1`, `A=2`. The query is very simple but I'm not sure why there is no output. I guess is the problem of the format for column A but I'm not sure what should I change in my formula so that the formula can work. Appreciate any help or advice!

Comment: You could also try `=QUERY(A3:C,"Where A matches '1|2'",0)`, or `QUERY(A3:C,"Where A matches '[12]'",0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A can't be both: 2 and 1. Instead try

```
=query(A3:C, "Where A = 2 or A = 1", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice I make the mistake there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It should have been OR not AND - it's impossible for any row in a particular column to have two values simultaneously:

```
=query(A3:C,"select * where A=1 or A=2",0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`QUERY()` is good choice. You can also use `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER(A3:C,A3:A>=1,A3:A<=2)
```